# Brainteaser Locker Open or Closed? in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Trying to code the classic brainteaser locker problem (the one where you open/close 100 lockers). When I run the code I wrote it does not give me the correct answer of 10 open lockers, but instead says all lockers are closed. I think I'm missing something in my loops...any suggestions? Thanks.

```
 def lockerproblem
      j = 0
      lockers = []

      while j < 100
       lockers << "open"
       j += 1
      end 

       a = 1
       i = 0

       while a <= 100
       while i < 100
        if ( i + 1 ) % a == 0
          if lockers[i] == "open"
            lockers[i] = "closed"
          else
            lockers[i] = "open"
          end
        end
        i += 1
      end
      a += 1
    end

    lockers[3] = "open"

    lockers.each do |text|
      puts text
    end
  end

  lockerproblem
```

Comment: Without a problem statement (e.g., context) I have no idea what's supposed to happen, or why. For example, why would it be "correct" to say 10 lockers are open? I only see code that will set everything to closed then set the fourth locker to open, which is exactly what happens.

Comment: You may consider it a "classic brainteaser problem", I have no idea what the problem is or what you're trying to achieve.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I am guessing that the brainteaser problem is this one - http://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/7824/100-closed-lockers.html

Comment: Suppose you're in a hallway lined with 100 closed lockers. 
You begin by opening every locker. Then you close every second locker. Then you go to every third locker and open it (if it's closed) or close it (if it's open). Let's call this action toggling a locker. Continue toggling every nth locker on pass number n. After 100 passes, where you toggle only locker #100, how many lockers are open?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Thank you for the help Justin. That's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this for array initialization:

```
lockers = ["open"] * 100
```

Think about your `i` variable: when is it set to 0? What will that mean to the inner loop? E.g.,

```
a, b = 0, 0
while a < 2
  while b < 2
    puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}"
    b += 1
  end
  a += 1
end
```

Outputs:

```
a=0, b=0
a=0, b=1
```

In other words, you *don't* see:

```
a=0, b=0
a=0, b=1
a=1, b=0
a=1, b=1
```

Why? Because `b` is incremented to `2`, is never reset, and the inner loop only executes once. Perhaps you are setting the initial value of `i` in the wrong place, where "wrong" means "outside the outer loop".

Lastly, opening the fourth locker (`locker[3]`) will throw off the results.

There are a number of small tweaks that could make the code a bit easier to understand (heck I might even define an `open?` method on String for the purposes of this small example), but this should be enough to get you the answer you expect.

---

Such monkey-patching isn't always a good idea, particularly on Ruby internals. But it allows some easy and nice-looking stuff like this:

```
> lockers.find_all(&:closed?).size
=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the right answer by making three changes:

- `i` needs to be reset to 0 at the start of each iteration of `a`
- The lockers should start as `closed`
- Remove the extra `lockers[3] = "open"` line

The updated code:

```
def lockerproblem
    j = 0
    lockers = []

    while j < 100
        lockers << "closed"
        j += 1
    end

    a = 1
    i = 0

    while a <= 100
        i = 0
        while i < 100
            if ( i + 1 ) % a == 0

              if lockers[i] == "open"

                lockers[i] = "closed"
              else

                lockers[i] = "open"
              end
            end
            i += 1
        end
        a += 1
    end

    lockers.each do |text|
        puts text
    end
end

lockerproblem
```

Comment: IMO when someone is trying to solve a brain teaser, it's better to hint rather than do their work for them, which is why my answer from 20+ minutes ago is less explicit.